# how to use injection token from component to service

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a boolean value in a component which i would like to inject in a service (it was required that way). I m a little confused how to achieve this. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Here getting the value as parameter in route. (isRecon)

```
path: ':system/cases/:dataSource',
        component: ScopedInjectorComponent,
        resolve: {
          dataSource: CaseDataSourceResolver,
        },
        data: {
          component: CaseTileComponent,
          parameters:{isRecon: true},
          providers: [caseSearchProviderFactory],
        } as ScopedInjectorData<CaseTileComponent>,
      },
```

here reading it in the component CaseTile

```
@Input()
  set isRecon(isRecon: boolean) {
    this._isRecon = isRecon;
  }
```

and in the CaseTileConfigurationService, i need to inject this value isRecon with a token and read from it.

```
constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CASE_SEARCH_SERVICE_CONFIGURATION_SERVICE)) private readonly configurationService: BaseCaseDataSourceConfigurationService,
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => ACCESS_AREA_SERVICE)) private readonly accessAreaService: BaseAccessAreaService,
    private _iStaticService: InvestigationsStaticDataService,
  ) {
  }
```

Comment: Can you expand on *i would like to inject in a service (it was required that way)*? This doesn't make much sense read at face value. Pleas be clear what you hope to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Injecting a component into a service is, in my opinion, not the right approach. It's akin to injecting a RestController into a Service in a Spring Boot application.
A Service typically a standalone, reusable class that can be used in various Angular components.
As a solution, you should set your boolean over service method from the component. But service should be injected into the component.

```
@Component {
 .....
}
export class YourComponent {
 _isRecon: boolean
 @Input() set isRecon(isRecon: boolean) {
    this._isRecon = isRecon;
 }
 
 constructor(private service: YourService) AfterViewInit{
 }

 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.setSomeBoolean(isRecon)
 }

}
```